# For what values of $k$ does the determinant of this matrix 'vanish?'

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, gaussian-elimination

\begin{bmatrix} 
 k & 1 & 4 \\  
 1 & k & 3 \\
 1 & 0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}

So I think to co-factor expand along the 3rd row giving me

$$1(3-4k)-0+1(k^2-1)$$

Which I guess can be solved to a weird quadratic that doesn't seem to get me anywhere. I was doing this because I thought this would reveal what k give me a determinant equal to $0$. Which would answer my question.

Do I need to perform row operations beforehand? Or is there another method to finding the values of k to satisfy the question?

Thanks in advance, tips/hints/solutions are appreciated :)

Comment: You began right! go on and set the expansion = 0. It's a trivial second degree equation $k^2-4k+2=0$

Comment: Your polynomial is correct now find the values for $P(k)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine.

$$k^2+3-4k-1=0$$

$$k^2-4k+2=0$$

Use the formula $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Comment: Yeah thank you for the guidance. Solved it to vanish for values of $2+\sqrt{2}$ and $2-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: checking: $(2+\sqrt{2})+(2-\sqrt2)=4$, $(2+\sqrt2)(2-\sqrt2)=4-2=2$. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

You're going in entirely the right direction. It's not a weird quadratic at all. It's just that the unknown is called $k$ instead of $x$, and you need to rearrange it a little and set it equal to $0$ to get it on the standard form.

Comment: Oh, I felt I was entirely off. But yeah solving through looks to be correct for this. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I had been looking at my approach for a while convinced I was incorrect.

Comment: @99Fishing It's not wasting our time at all. If we felt it was wasting our time, we wouldn't have answered. You posted a clear question, and details of exactly what you tried, how far you got and where you got stuck, which is all we ask for in a question. How "obvious" the solution is, either to us, or to you in hindsight, has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @99Fishing Agree with Arthur. Good job including your attempts and thoughts.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance. I don't like posting here unless I can lay out an attempt of my own and articulate why I think it is/isn't working. I feel that it helps me learn from any responses better since they can relate whatever they may hint, solve or guide towards using what I've done so far or where I've gone wrong. Have a good one!